# Восстановление системы Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

У меня такая проблема, есть система Windows 7 Professional x86. На диске C в папке Sysytem Volume Information есть порядка 15гб файлов, но нет ни одной точки восстановления в списке, т.е. не отображаются точки восстановления. Можно ли каким нибудь способом восстановить систему с помощью этих файлов?

Comment: Ты уже что-то сломал?

Comment: Вроде нет, но мне нужно восстановить систему

Comment: Зачем восстанавливать, если всё работает?

Comment: ну была одна программа вот она и перестала работать

Comment: хочу вернуть в то состояние когда она работала

Comment: Если снимков нет, то никак. Да и при наличии снимоков - тоже не всегда получается.